Failed to publish ontology type outputs `OntologyMetadata:ManyToManyLinkTypePrimaryKeyMismatch`
So I had a previous many to many relationship in Pipeline Builder (that i’ve since deleted) but my build is still referencing it somehow and failing, but I can’t figure out where to investigate more logs based on the error id c825e27b-..
Where can I go with that id to investigate? It does not look like an RID, which I also know you can just query for, but don’t know where if anyone can share that answer too
OntologyMetadata:ManyToManyLinkTypePrimaryKeyMismatch

c825e27b-1402-4d5f-a1ab-xxxxxxxxxx

Ultimately I want to kill any reference to the many-to-many as I no longer need it

Found it in console and have been using AIP assist but not much further
{
    "status": {
        "targetIds": [
            "e3a3a479-0313-417a-9575-18049a1b2a1b",
            "d06fb57e-d0a7-4bdc-9ade-1043a47063b4",
            "a17e490b-90fa-4bea-83fa-595f892486f7",
            "40258912-24e1-4624-8bc4-50c2bc3e44ff",
            "64abcae1-a09b-4ce7-808c-760c247fdcfc",
            "8de2c890-3776-4ffc-bc5a-d26904b96f4a",
            "653ea8f8-9e7f-481c-bb58-02d823f0b9ff",
            "e9ae1224-d810-47f7-b91e-84ff1ccd112a",
            "48d4696f-b923-4c80-9e0d-62a505342ad5",
            "6a31783e-4738-4da4-8cb4-7c4b19146d7a",
            "291fc9f8-5a99-4c02-8115-9f442ea311bd",
            "722ae220-764f-4a80-be76-2998d07299ff",
            "c1821925-8f80-4385-b9cc-eebc1fa1b634",
            "2e7c0ccf-2f61-4e48-8e0e-957ab42afd4e",
            "c79827e1-ef39-4371-8d14-9760fba75fc8",
            "95723036-e1fc-4829-981e-9cf83c1f7d35",
            "ffceeef4-a87a-4cea-b611-431160fd80c9",
            "d61247b6-7166-46f4-8c73-559c08026374"
        ],
        "error": {
            "errorInstanceId": "a74319ea-8ec2-473c-ac67-e73da619da71",
            "errorName": "OntologyMetadata:ManyToManyLinkTypePrimaryKeyMismatch",
            "__typename": "OntologyPublishTaskError_Generic"
        },
        "__typename": "EddieOntologyPublishTaskStatus_Failed"
    },
    "__typename": "EddieSandboxDeploymentTask_OntologyPublish"
},


Resolution from support
The issue was exactly what you described in the issue you raised. The many-to-many link between the two Objects was deleted from the pipeline builder but was still in the ontology and was blocking you from publishing anything new to the Ontology.
I went in the Ontology and deleted manually this many-to-many link and it unblocked everything.
I will flag this to our product team as the expected behavior is that if you delete the link from Pipeline Builder then it also deletes it in the Ontology.
